# How to reload page once only without repeating loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to reload page only once after submitting some data using JQuery.

code to reload page :

`update: the url here is not ending with '?' because it has parameter value
for example: http://localhost:49208/UserView.aspx?id=12`

```
  var url = window.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) 
        {
         window.location.href = url;
        }
```

The problem here is that page reloading does not stop?

Comment: add a new query string key value that says `&alreadyReloaded=yes` and check for it in your javascript

Answer (score 2):

The reason it won't stop reloading is because you aren't changing the conditions of the url; so if the if statement is ever true, it will happen again and again.

If you want to reload the page, just use `window.location.reload();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this logic.

```
if (url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
    url = url + '?';
    location = '?';
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to add a flag variable so that javascript can check whether the page is reloaded previously.

```
 var url = window.location.href; // get the current url of page into variable
 if (url.indexOf('?') > -1) { // url has a '?'
     if(url.indexOf('reloaded') < 0){ // url does not have the text 'reloaded'
          url = url + "&reloaded=true"; // add the word 'reloaded' to url
          window.location = url; // "reload" the page
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reload the page only once, use the following method:

```
    if(!window.location.hash) {
       window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
       window.location.reload();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!window.location.hash) 
{
    window.location = window.location + '#loaded';

    window.location.reload();
}
```